# Using Canvas instead of Scaleform in UDK

Tags: udk, scripting, hud

I'm working with Unreal Script, and I need to use Canvas instead of Scaleform to create a HUD.  I've extended the game type from UTGame, and used bUseClassicHUD in the Default Properties section, but the default Scaleform HUD continues to appear.  I know for certain that I have everything configured properly to load and run the scripts, but this one line just doesn't seem to have any effect.

```
DefaultProperties{

// Disable the scaleform (flash) HUD in the UTGame
bUseClassicHUD = true

// Initial score value
nScore = 0

// Initial time value
m_gameTimer = 30.0
```

}

Is there something else I need to include?  I've done a reinstall (I'm using the July 2013 build), but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

After moving the opening curly brace onto the next line, the code worked as intended.  I'm not sure why it has to be on a separate line here in particular, but it solved the problem.

Comment: Ah! Unreal's parser has improved a lot over the years, but it still can be finicky. I guess it didn't like your defaultproperties block.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's the scaleform HUD that's appearing? I'd try logging out the `newHUDType` parameter you're getting in `ClientSetHUD()`. If bUseClassicHUD is true, it looks like you should be getting the UTHUD class (granted, I have an older drop of UDK, so things may have changed in more recent builds.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely the scaleform HUD still.  The HUD class that I'm making is extended from the standard HUD class, does it need to extend from UTHUD for Canvas to work?

Comment: No, that should be fine.